# SQL Server select first instance of ranked data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that creates a result set like this:

```
Rank   Name
1      Fred
1      John
2      Mary
2      Fred
2      Betty
3      John
4      Betty
4      Frank
```

I need to then select the lowest rank for each name, e.g.:

```
Rank   Name
1      Fred
1      John
2      Mary
2      Betty
4      Frank
```

Can this be done within TSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(Rank) AS Rank, Name
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 4):

yes

```
select name, min(rank)
from nameTable
group by name
```

Answer (score 3):

As Paul + Kevin have pointed out, simple cases of returning a value from an aggregate can be extracted using `MIN / MAX` etc (just note that `RANK` is a reserved word)

In a more general / complicated case, e.g. where you need to find the second  / Nth highest rank, you can use `PARTITION`s with `ROW_NUMBER()` to do ranking and then filter by the rank.

```
SELECT [Rank], [Name]
FROM
(
    SELECT [RANK], [Name], 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Rank]) as [RowRank]
    FROM [MyTable]
) AS [MyTableReRanked]
WHERE [RowRank] = @N
ORDER BY [Rank];
```

Comment: Thank you @StuartLC.  Helped with a problem related to the second highest for me.